# React css import not working in cdn when i am imporing in head

Tags: css, reactjs

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./styles.css"  />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      class Home extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <img src="bg.jpeg" alt="Snow" style={{ width:'100% ', height:'672px' }}/>
              <div class="centered" style={{ background: '#1E1721', padding: '2cm', borderRadius: '5px' }}>
                <img src="logo.png" style={{ width:'200px',marginBottom:'2cm' }} />
                <a href="inventories.html">
                  <p style={{ color:'#fff', textAlign:'center' }}>
                    Электронный каталог
                  </p>
                </a>
                <a href="standards.html">
                  <p style={{ color:'#fff',textAlign:'center' }}>
                    Нормативы
                  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>  
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Home />,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi, Here I am trying to use cdn in react.js but I have one css file names **styles.css** . I have added it in my head tag.

But it is not applying any styles to my app.

Same way if am using bootstrap cdn link it is working.

Is my import wrong for css ? But I can see my css in view source.

Please have a look

Comment: why are you adding jsx in html file? and add script bottom of body

Comment: I just need this to work anyway. Can you tell me how to make css work?

Answer (score 0):

The `public` folder allows one to add assets outside of the module system. However, if you put a file into the public folder, **it will not be processed** by Webpack. Instead it will be copied into the build folder untouched. To reference assets in the `public` folder, you need to use an environment variable called `PUBLIC_URL`.

With that in mind perhaps you could try changing your `<link>` tag to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="%PUBLIC_URL%/styles.css"  />
```

For more information check out the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) on using the `public` folder.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Do i just need my line with yours ?

Comment: Yes, change your link reference to what I put, then rebuild your project if desired.

Comment: I did but still not working. Styles showing in viewsource but not applying

Comment: Did you rebuild your project? If so, the environment variable will be replaced appropriately. If you are running in dev mode replace your link with the following: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/styles.css"  />`

Comment: I am only using one html and one css file. I can't build. I am checking by refreshing the page

Comment: try changing your link to what I mentioned in the comment above

Comment: Did exactly same but still css not applying.

Comment: In network tab showing failed to load response data

Answer (score 0):

Replace class with className it will work fine. I was missing that